# Gnome-terminal blinking cursor gone after changing input-method

Tags: gnome-terminal, input-method, japanese

I have just moved to Japan and I bought the "ATOK X3 for Linux" software to properly input Japanese characters. 
It is a marvelous piece of software that I was already using in Windows and I paid it a premium but I think it was worth the money.
Anyway, I managed to install it on Ubuntu 17.10, even if it is quite an old version. I have followed the two guides below:

1. [Japanese](http://r03.nurse.medic.mie-u.ac.jp/Ubuntu/UbuntuXenial.html#sec12) [English](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fr03.nurse.medic.mie-u.ac.jp%2FUbuntu%2FUbuntuXenial.html%23sec12&sandbox=1)
2. [Japanese](https://sicklylife.jp/ubuntu/1404/settings.html#atok_in) [English](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fsicklylife.jp%2Fubuntu%2F1404%2Fsettings.html%23atok_in)

Now everything is working except for a little but annoying thing, apparently completely unrelated to the software.
The thing is that in the gnome-terminal the blinking cursor that shows the position is gone. 
As soon as the ATOK software is started the cursor disappears, just like  the command

```
 setterm -cursor off
```

was issued (but it isn't actually).
Again I am not talking about the mouse cursor. Only the blinking cursor in the terminal.
**Do you know how could I bring it back?** Typing anything in the terminal has become a real pain in the back!
Thank you

(maybe) relevant info:

```
 $ uname -a
 Linux zion 4.13.0-38-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 14 15:20:44 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

- Lenovo Carbon X1 Gen6
- ATOK X3 for Linux Tech Ver.20
- GNOME Shell 3.26.2 (Adapta-Nokto theme)
- iiimf input method

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this is happening with both IBus and fcitx, GNOME version 3.28.2 gnome-terminal version 3.28.2. After some messing around I think I figured it out - for me the cursor was dissapearing when I ran GNOME on wayland, switching to GNOME on X fixed it. If you're still experiencing this issue perhaps you can confirm this? If so I'll try and file a bug report.

Comment: thank you for the answer but perhaps our issues are uncorrelated because I experience the same issue in X as well (and only for the iiimf input method). I tried ATOK on Ubuntu 18.04 and the situation is not improved or changed in the least.